# Mysql JSON_EXTRACT() и алиас в path

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

Всем привет, имеется MYSQL 5.7 и таблица где в одном стобце имеется json с несколькими массивами.

```
[
  {
    "id": "158",
    "rank": 100,
  },
  {
    "id": "8861",
    "rank": 96,
  }
]
```

Я пытаюсь выцепить записи по значению id и отсортировать по rank
После долгих изысканий у меня получилась следующая конструкция:

```
SELECT atg, JSON_EXTRACT(json, atg) as rank
 from (SELECT 
            REPLACE (JSON_SEARCH(json, 'all', '158', NULL, '$[*].id'), "id", 'rank') as atg,
            id, 
            json->'$[*].rank', json
            from table 
            WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json, 'all', '158', NULL, '$[*].id') is not null
      ) as list ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Получается с помощью replace() я найденое id превращаю в rank и использую это в качестве path в JSON_EXTRACT()
Сам алиас получается корректным

```
"$[0].rank"
```

Но JSON_EXTRACT ни как не хочет его принимать говоря что

```
#3143 - Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1.
```

В общем вопроса два, как его заставить принимать алиас, и если есть альтернативный способ решения данной задачи, пожалуйста посоветуйте.

PS
*@atg:=*
Тоже без результата

Всех с наступающим!

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: B вам добрый вечер, оставил жалобу за токсичность, хорошего вам дня.

Comment: Ну-ну... лучше бы выполнил данные в теме по ссылке рекомендации. Впрочем, если основная цель - не решить проблему, а оставить жалобу...

Comment: Вы продолжайте говорить не по теме вопроса. Я бы вам посоветовал его прочитать прежде чем писать рекомендации не по теме. Перестаньте проявлять враждебность.